# OpenGL translation

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm having some problems translating an object I'm drawing. This is the entirety of my display function. I can't seem to find anything I'm doing wrong.

```
glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glPushMatrix();
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0, 720, 480, 0, -1.0, 1.0);
glTranslatef(-0.5f,0.0f,0.0f);

//drawing object here

glPopMatrix();
glutSwapBuffers();
```

Comment: What's wrong? What do you expect? What's happening?

Comment: are you setting color?

Comment: and also, do you know that you are translating 1/1440 of screen? are you drawing the same sized object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to start modifying the modelview matrix stack after you've done `glOrtho`:

```
// ...
glOrtho(0, 720, 480, 0, -1.0, 1.0);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glTranslatef(-0.5f,0.0f,0.0f);
// ...
```

But now your `glPushMatrix` and `glPopMatrix` are modifying different stacks, so the `glPopMatrix` will result in an error. You shouldn't need them for such a simple example anyway.

Comment: Much appreciated. This was actually it. The example I've given is simple but the object I'm drawing is rather complex. Thank you very much

Comment: Now the object does move to the left as expected, but it does so every frame until it drifts away. Any idea how to solve this problem? I want to move the object to the left by -0.5 (so that each frame it will be at that location). And I only want to move this one object. As there are more that are being drawn.

Comment: @user2111311 Make sure you do `glLoadIdentity()` before you start doing the transformations each frame.